# Set EmployeeName default to current user

Tags: default-value

I don't see a way to default the EmployeeName column (person or group type) to current user. Is there a powershell way to set this up? I am not sure if the following code will work for Person and Group type column? I saw some jquery way but I rather go with OOTB if it's possible.

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://inside.nov.com
$l = $w.GetListFromUrl("/Lists/EmployeeSurvey/AllItems.aspx")
$f = $l.Fields["EmployeeName"]
$f.DefaultValue = "[ME]"
$f.Update()
```

I tested jquery and it works perfectly with new form by adding cewp and reference the js from asset library.

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/set-people-picker-default-value-to-current-user.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking it is not possible to set a default value on a people field.  But, you might be able to accomplish your requirement another way. For example,

- A workflow
- A list item event receiver
- Some JavaScript on the new item form that prepopulates the form field.

...And, there is a [third party tool](http://www.sharepointadd-ons.com/sharepoint_default_value) that claims to do what you're looking for. As is always worth mentioning with third party tools, your mileage may vary.